# I need to count volume group free space in percents

Tags: awk, grep, lvm

I got how to grep total size and how much free space is there:

```
vgdisplay | grep 'VG Size' | awk '{print $3}' &&  vgdisplay | grep Free | awk '{print $7}'
99.53
54.41
```

now I need to extend this command to count how much free space is there in percents
should counts like:

```
 "total space" / 100% * "free space"
```

Comment: isn't the output that `vgdisplay` gives you is already in percentage? so all you just need to do  is: `vgdisplay |awk '/VG Size/{ print $3 } /Free/{ print $7"%" }'`

Comment: @αғsнιη it’s not a percentage, it’s the available size in the closest appropriate unit (by default).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vgs` and tailor the output format instead, to reduce the number of steps:

```
sudo vgs --units b --no-suffix --noheadings -o vg_name,vg_size,vg_free | awk '{ printf "%s %f%%\n", $1, $3 * 100 / $2 }'
```

This forces output in bytes (`--units b`), removes suffixes and headings, and outputs only the VG’s name, total size, and free space, before converting the latter two into a percentage.

If you need all three values:

```
... | awk '{ printf "%s %d %d %f%%\n", $1, $2, $3, $3 * 100 / $2 }'
```